# Printing text on the chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have written a javascript page using High charts api to draw a chart.

Everything is working fine. But when I am trying to print a text on the chart I am facing some problems.

In the below URL you can check the code and running chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/uVTNU/14/

I am using the below code snippet to get the text on the chart.

```
var text = chart.renderer.text(
                '500',
                57 ,                
                112.1
            ).css({
                color: '#F00',
                fontSize: '11px'                
            }).add();
```

Here I have taken x and y values as (57,112.1) which has taken from inspect elements.

"180" is the place where we want to print the text.

My requirement is : we want to print the text "500" above 180.

That is why I have chosen the co-ordinates mentioned above.

But the text "500" is printing after "180" even the x and y positions are same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try using x-35,y-100.
PS: this is not a standard solution just patch work.!!

Comment: yes use different values, have you tried changing them? Play around the values to get it where you want

Comment: Thanks Jugal. We have already tried in that way and succeed. But we need to make that dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/uVTNU/20/)

you need to change the `x` attribute in `tspan` , you code was changing the `text x-cord` tag which was not doing anything

```
  $.each($('svg text tspan') , function(index, value){
    var myval = 500 ; // change this variable as required 
    if($(this).text() == myval){
       $(this).attr('x' , 40) ; // X-cord 
        $(this).parents('text').attr('y' ,100) ; //y-cord
    }

   });
```